# Como enviar múltiples archivos con ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, react-hooks

Necesito enviar un array con documentos atravez de ajax al servidor,cuando mando uno a uno en un FormData funciona bien pero cuando los envio todos juntos no.

```
  var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("files", files);
client()
  .post(`audit/masiveDocument/${audit.audit_id}`,  formData)
  .then(({ data }) => {
    alertSuccess("Documentos cargado exitosamente");
    setAudit({ ...audit, status: STATUS_NOT_LOADED });
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    if (e.request.status === 401) {
      logout();
    } else if (e.request.status === 422) {
      setErrors({ error: e.response.data, status: true });
    } else if (e.request.status === 403) {
      history.push("/app/unauthorized");
    } else {
      alertError("Error al guardar los documentos");
    }
  });
```

Al retornar de api lo que llega se ve asi

```
files: "[object File],[object File],[object File],[object File],[object File],[object File],[object File],[object File],[object File],[object File],[object File],[object File],[object File],[object File],[object File]"
```

Pero si lo envio sin FormData llega bien como array pero solo con la ruta y el tipo  sin documento

Comment: Hola. Yo nunca he enviado archivos vía ajax. Pero, en tu construcción de formData observo que no le asignas el atributo **enctype = "multipart/form-data"** Sin ese atributo no hay transporte de archivos

Answer (score 0):

El `append` de `FormData` no permite adjuntar varios archivos de golpe, la solución esta en adjuntar los archivos uno a uno en la misma `key`.

Cambiando esta linea:

```
formData.append("files", files);
```

Por esta:

```
files.forEach(file => formData.append("files", file));
```

Deberia hacer que funcione correctamente, aunque si estas usando PHP, sera mejor que cambies el nombre de la `key` de `files` a `files[]`:

```
files.forEach(file => formData.append("files[]", file));
```

Comment: los recorre correctamente pero quedan vacios  `files: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
0: {}
1: {}
2: {}
3: {}
4: {}
5: {}
6: {}
7: {}
8: {}
9: {}
10: {}
11: {}
12: {}
13: {}
14: {}`

Comment: asi se ve el form   `files[]: (binary)
files[]: (binary)
files[]: (binary)
files[]: (binary)
files[]: (binary)
files[]: (binary)
files[]: (binary)
files[]: (binary)
files[]: (binary)
files[]: (binary)
files[]: (binary)
files[]: (binary)
files[]: (binary)
files[]: (binary)
files[]: (binary)`

Comment: Segun el form parece que esta bien, prueba cambiando el `foreach` por un `for` no vaya a ser que este sea la causa

Answer (score 0):

Una solución temporal es enviarlos en una posición aparte,y en el backen convertir el request en array

```
    var formData = new FormData();
files.forEach((file,key) => formData.append(`file${key}`, file));
```

en api recorrer

```
$files=[];
  foreach ($request->all() as $file) {
    array_push($files,$file);
  }
```